# R: Ordered selection without repeatition within groups

Tags: r

Say I have a vector of elements divided by group, I am looking for a way of getting the ordered selection of elements without repeatition by group.
The example will probably clarify:

```
group<-c("a","a","a","b","b","b")
element<-c(1,2,3,1,2,3)
data<-data.frame(group,element)
```

I would like to get:

```
group<-c("a","a","a","b","b","b")
element.x<-(1,1,2,1,1,2)
element.y<-(2,3,3,2,3,3)
data<-data.frame(group, element.x,element.y)
```

I have tried to work with left_join from dplyr but it gives me all the combinations (i.e.  (1,2) and (2,1) and it is not what I am looking for).

```
require(dplyr)
data<- data %>%
left_join(data , by=c("group"))
```

Possibly, I would prefer something that can work even if the variable "element" is a string.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `combn` with `tapply`.

```
group <- c("a","a","a","b","b","b")
element <- c(1,2,3,1,2,3)
data <- data.frame(group,element)

# get per group, all unique combinations
combinations <- tapply(data$element, data$group, combn, 2)

# get number of unique combinations per group
nPerComb <- sapply(combinations, NCOL) 

# bind combinations to a matrix
elements <- t(do.call(cbind, combinations))

# fill dataframe with new information
data2 <- data.frame(
    group = rep(unique(data$group), nPerComb),
    element.x = elements[, 1],
    element.y = elements[, 2]
)
```

This also works for character data but not for factors (those will be converted to numeric).